# How to group time column into 5 minute intervals and max/min value respectively SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a database with a **Datetime** column containing intervals of +/- 30 seconds and a **Value** column containing random numbers between 10 and 100. My table looks like this:

```
datetime               value
----------------------------
2016-05-04 20:47:20    12
2016-05-04 20:47:40    44
2016-05-04 20:48:30    56
2016-05-04 20:48:40    25
2016-05-04 20:49:30    92
2016-05-04 20:49:40    61
2016-05-04 20:50:00    79
2016-05-04 20:51:20    76
2016-05-04 20:51:30    10
2016-05-04 20:51:40    47
2016-05-04 20:52:40    23
2016-05-04 20:54:00    40
2016-05-04 20:54:10    18
2016-05-04 20:54:50    12
2016-05-04 20:56:00    55
```

What I want the following output:

```
datetime               max_val    min_val
-----------------------------------------
2016-05-04 20:45:00    92         12
2016-05-04 20:50:00    79         10
2016-05-04 20:55:00    55         55
```

Before I can even continue getting the maximum value and the minimum value, I first have to **GROUP** the **datetime** column into 5 minute intervals. According to my research I came up with this:

```
SELECT
  time,
  value
FROM random_number_minute
GROUP BY
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 300
```

Which actually **GROUPS** the datetime column into 5 minute intervals like this:

```
datetime
-------------------
2016-05-04 20:47:20
2016-05-04 20:50:00
2016-05-04 20:56:00
```

This comes very close as it takes the next closest **datetime** to, in this case, `20:45:00`, `20:50:00`, etc. I would like to **rounddown** the **datetime** to the nearest 5 minutes regardless of the **seconds**, for instance if the minutes are:

```
minutes    rounddown
--------------------
10         10
11         10
12         10
13         10
14         10
15         15
16         15
17         15
18         15
19         15
20         20
```

The time could be **14:59** and I would like to **rounddown** to **10:00**. I also tried using this after hours of research:

```
SELECT
    time,
    time_rounded =
    dateadd(mi,(datepart(mi,dateadd(mi,1,time))/5)*5,dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,dateadd(mi,1,time)),0))
```

But sadly this did not work. I get this error:

*Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff'*

I tried this too:

```
SELECT  
    time, CASE  
          WHEN  DATEDIFF(second, DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, 0, time_out) / 300 * 300, 0), time) >= 240
            THEN    DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(second, 0, time) / 300 * 300) + 300, 0)
            ELSE    DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, 0, time) / 300 * 300, 0)
          END
```

Returning the same error.

How can I do this? And after the **datetime** is grouped, how can I get the max and min value of the data grouping?

Comment: I am using MySQL. Sorry for the mistake. To be precise MyWebSQL a plugin for Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I'm repeating another answer. I'll delete if I am..

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/300)*300) x
     , MIN(value) min_value
     , MAX(value) max_value 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY x;
```

Comment: I like your approach @Strawberry Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use various date partition functions inside a GROUP BY.

Code:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(300 * round(unix_timestamp(r.datetime)/300)) AS 5datetime,
MAX(r.value) AS max_value, 
MIN(r.value) As min_value,
(SELECT r.value FROM random_number_minute ra WHERE ra.datetime = r.datetime order by ra.datetime desc LIMIT 1) as first_val
FROM random_number_minute r
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.datetime) DIV 300
```

Output:

```
5datetime               max_value   min_value   first_val
May, 04 2016 20:45:00   92          12          12
May, 04 2016 20:50:00   79          10          79
May, 04 2016 20:55:00   55          55          55
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16b1/17/0

Comment: Same approach as mine. Simply rounding the time instead of using `DIV`. I'll give it a try now @Matt Thanks for your answer

Comment: Updated for first val, need to have a think for last val

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    timestamp(concat(date(time), ' ', hour(time), ':', minute(time) div 5 * 5)) as floor_time,
    min(value),
    max(value)
FROM random_number_minute
GROUP BY date(time), hour(time), minute(time) div 5 * 5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91212f/5