# Explain MySQL Query for "How to group time column into 5 minute intervals"

Tags: mysql

I found various solution for the problem like here:

[How to group time column into 5 minute intervals and max/min value respectively SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050433/how-to-group-time-column-into-5-minute-intervals-and-max-min-value-respectively)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195353/grouping-data-into-5-minute-intervals-within-a-time-range

[Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

The code solving the task looks like:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp) DIV 300) * 300) AS Timestamp,
val AS AgregatedValue
From foo
GROUP BY Timestamp
ORDER BY Timestamp
```

Can someone explain why the solution provided works? 
I couldn't find an answer with a nice description of how it actually works.
Why do you DIV by 300 seconds in the first place and finally multiply by 300 seconds? 
What happens in the "background"?

I read the documentation about `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)` which returns the value of the argument as an unsigned integer in seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC. 
I know that `FROM_UNIXTIME()`happens to be the reverse function of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)`

Maybe this question is stupid, however I am stuck.

Comment: It's a good question, not stupid! We would think `/ 300) * 300` is obsolete, but you figured out there is something "in the background" going on. So I find this a very smart and clever question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the token `DIV`.

`DIV` is not only dividing (`/`), but also casting to integer implicitly.

You do this to get an integer number without remainder. Basically, this is the same as using an explicit cast after dividing, or using `ROUND()` or `FLOOR()` after dividing.

Ref:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html

> Integer division. Discards from the division result any fractional
>   part to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp)` contain a date stored  as the the number of second  strating from  1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC.

in 5 minutes you have 300 second

so the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp)` by 300 return the number of part you have in number for each 300..
 this integer  part  is a number that multipied  by 300

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp) DIV 300) * 300
```

return a each number of seconds for each 5 minutes

the last conversion

```
  FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp) DIV 300) * 300)
```

return  the date and is used  for group by

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.timestamp) DIV 300) * 300) AS Timestamp,
val AS AgregatedValue
From foo
GROUP BY Timestamp
ORDER BY Timestamp
```